# how to execute set of commands in elevated mode of powershell

Tags: powershell

i have tried the below way to execute the commands in administrator mode.

`PS>start-process powershell -verb runas $app = Get-AppxPackage -all| Where-Object{$_.Name-like "*$ReleaseName*"}`

`PS>start-process powershell -verb runas Remove-AppxPackage $app.PackageFullName`

- for the first call, it opens and executes the command successfully and closes the admin powershell instance. for the second call it requires $app information which is not available because it again opens a new PS admin window
- i can't execute `Get-AppxPackage -all` in normal mode `-all` requires admin mode only

tried the below but no luck.

```
PS>start-process powershell -verb runas 
{

$app = Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object{$_.Name-like "*$ReleaseName*"};

Remove-AppxPackage $app.PackageFullName

}
```

can someone suggest me how to execute set of instructions like above in powershell elevated mode?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The obvious way:

Open Powershell console in "elevated mode" -> Right click shortcut / exe and click `Run as Administrator`. Or in start menu, type Powershell and hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Then run the commands from this.

Or you can have the commands in a script (.ps1 file) and invoke that script:

```
start-process powershell -verb runas -argument script.ps1
```

I would also like to mention that in yout commands, you don't have to store it in `$app`, you can use something like:

```
Get-AppxPackage -all| Where-Object{$_.Name-like "$ReleaseName"} | Remove-AppxPackage
```