# Send a command to a powershell opened with "Start-Process powershell -Verb runas"

Tags: redirect, powershell, admin, pipe

I want to open an admin powershell and send it a command (eventually a script).  Right now, it doesn't matter what command, but I've tried things like:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runas < $something
```

or

```
$something | Start-process powershell -Verb runas
```

just to get some text to show up in the new admin powershell window.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That awkward moment when you do a little more research and find what you want: this link will help anyone: [how to execute set of commands in elevated mode of powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681920/how-to-execute-set-of-commands-in-elevated-mode-of-powershell?rq=1)

Essentially, add the -argument argument to your command

```
Start-Process powershell -verb runas -argument dir
```